macOS 14.5 Finder desktop no longer moves files to trash when pressing Command+Delete
I'm on my MacBook Pro M1 running macOS 14.5 using the built in keyboard. Every file I delete via Command+Delete pops up a confirmation for deleting permanently instead of just moving to trash immediately.
How do I restore previous the behavior?
I am using macOS 14.5 and am using iCloud Drive for Desktop/Documents folders.
EDIT:
Oddly enough, the problem goes away when a reboot, then reverts back to the undesirable state after a few minutes.

It's a Finder preference, so look under "Finder > Preferences…"

@Spiff I've already disabled "Show warning before removing from iCloud drive".
